# Where does question mark belong?

Tags: punctuation

Where is question mark on below?  After What or Alan

"What?" yelled Alan.

Comment: Where is the question?  Where does it end?

Answer (score 0):

Where you have it. The quotes contain one short sentence; that sentence is a question, so it gets a question mark. The whole thing is a larger sentence, in this case a statement, so it is finished with the full stop.